# How to divide an array to chunks with flexible output length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, divide

How to divide an array to chunks with flexible output length? 
it's necessary for render pagination, where we have limited place for elements, 
and if we have several pages of elements — we need to display buttons with arrays (prev/next) instead el's.

example `f()` input-output, when 1st argument is Array with data, 
and 2nd arg is maximum of elements in list, including nav-buttons:

```
      f([1,2,3,4], 4) => [1,2,3,4]
    f([1,2,3,4,5], 4) => [[1,2,3], [4,5]]
  f([1,2,3,4,5,6], 4) => [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 4) => [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7]]
f([7,6,5,4,3,2,1], 4) => [[7,6,5], [4,3], [2,1]]
f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 6) => [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7]]
```

**Example of design-layout with max 6 elements**

1st page: 
[image: 1st page]

2nd page: 
[image: 2nd page]

Last page: 
[image: Last page]

Comment: Kindly check your expected output once. It seems to be confusing.

Comment: are you looking for method to split arrays ? `splice()` ?

Comment: Take out four, until <8, then divide the rest into equal chunks.

Comment: Can you clarify more on why the below are split in this way
f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 4) => [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7]] and not [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7]]  as the previous  f([1,2,3,4,5,6], 4) => [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]?

Comment: Why `f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 4) => [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7]]`? Why not `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7]]`?

Comment: i am added more examples for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, determine if one page/two pages are enough. If not, loop the array.

```js
let f = (array, max) => {
  if (array.length / max <= 1)
    return array

  if (array.length / (max - 1) <= 2)
    return [array.slice(0, max - 1), array.slice(max - 1, array.length)]

  let result = []
  let n = 0
  while (n <= array.length - 1) {
    if (n == 0) {
      result.push(array.slice(n, n + max - 1))
      n += max - 1
    } else {
      let pushAmount = n+max-1 >= array.length ? max-1 : max-2
      result.push(array.slice(n, n + pushAmount))
      n += pushAmount
    }
  }

  return result
}

console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4], 4))
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4))
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4))
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 4))
console.log(f([7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 4))
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 6))
```

Comment: Works great, awesome, Richard!

Comment: @EugeneBalashov Glad I could help. Edited a little to make it terser.

Comment: and i think this code need string at start `if (max < 3) return array;` :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work !

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2];
result=[];
start = true;
function f(arr,n){
    if(arr.length >= n-2){
        console.log(start)
        if(start){
            start=false;
            result.push(arr.splice(0,n-1))
            return f(arr,n)
        }else{
            result.push(arr.splice(0,n-2))
            return f(arr,n)
        }
    } else {
        result.push(arr);
        return 1;
    }
}
f(a,6);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - with recursion. I felt this was a bit easier to understand.

```js
f = (arr, max, first = true) => {
  if (arr.length == 0) return []
  const last = arr.length <= max - !first
  const curLen = max - !first - !last
  const cur = arr.slice(0, curLen)
  const next = f(arr.slice(curLen), max, false)
  return [cur, ...next]
}


console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4], 4))
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4))
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4))
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 4))
console.log(f([7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 4))
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 6))
```